# Get a country unique identifier on user tap

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, geocoding

When a user taps a particular place on a `MapKit` map, I need to know if a country is a particular country (eg. *Spain*), then I must perform actions based on the retrieved information.

I initially thought to use the country name I get [from](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation):

```
reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, 
          completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

but the country name is strictly related to the device locale settings, so it's not really a good idea use the country name...

Then, I thought getting the `isoCountryCode` would have been a better choice, but, I don't know why in my tests `CLPlacemark` doesn't return it.

Finally, there's another version of the  `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` function, that lets you specify a `preferredLocale`. Is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/2908779-reversegeocodelocation) the way to go?

```
func reverseGeocodeLocation(_ location: CLLocation, 
            preferredLocale locale: Locale?, 
          completionHandler: @escaping CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get address info from lat & long,

**Swift**

```
     let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks, error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

            if pm.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                print(pm.country)
                print(pm.ISOcountryCode)
          }
    })

}
```

**Obj-C**

```
  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
        __block CLPlacemark *placemark = nil;

        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation
                       completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error){

                 NSLog(@"************************************* Geocode failed with error:************************************* \n %@", error);
             }else{
             placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSLog(@"Current placemark %@", placemark);
             NSLog(@"Current country code: %@", [placemark ISOcountryCode]);
          }
         }];
```

Comment: Have you red the question? I know how to get all the informations I need. Problem is I can't get a unique identifier for a country

Comment: ohh wait you mean like for India  , "IN" is a country code?

Comment: Exactly, BUT, problem is CLPlacemark doesn NOT always (in my tests NEVER) return the isoCountryCode   :-(

Comment: can you post your code in the question, i am using same in objective c to get `[placemark ISOcountryCode]`. I am not getting any issue.

Comment: Don't ask me why: I restarted Mac and XCode and now I can see the code retrieved. Another thing I don't understand is why printing placemark doesn't show anything related to the country iso (eg. Saraspur, Saraspur, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380002, India @ <+23.03383537,+72.61255204> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+23.03383536,+72.61255204> radius 141.83', center:<+23.03383536,+72.61255204>, radius:141.83m)